# Can you resolve my problem the link is not working but when i copy and paste the link from console it.s working?

Tags: mern

the link is not working <Link href={`/blog/detail?id=${blog._id}`}.

```
 { data && data.map((blog) => (
           
            <div className="col-12 col-lg-3 mb-6 mb-lg-0" key={blog._id}>
                {/* Blog Card */}
                <div className="card border-0 bg-transparent">
                    {/* <div className="position-absolute bg-white shadow-primary text-center p-2 rounded ml-3 mt-3">15
                        <br/>July
                    </div> */}
                    {/*<img className="card-img-top shadow rounded" src={`${blog.productImages[0]}`} alt="Image"/>*/}
                    <Link href={`/blog/detail?id=${blog._id}`}><img className="card-img-top shadow rounded_img" style={{height: "170px", width: "253px"}} src={BASE_URL+blog.productImages[0]} alt="Img"/></Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML Links use the `<a>` element not link, try replacing your last line with:

```
<a href={`/blog/detail?id=${blog._id}`}><img className="card-img-top shadow rounded_img" style={{height: "170px", width: "253px"}} src={BASE_URL+blog.productImages[0]} alt="Img"/></a>
```

See here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Also, try replacing className with `class` throughout your code.